# Does loading the game on a different system count as changing the clock?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

In Pokémon Omega Ruby and Alpha Sapphire, there are a number of time-sensitive events (daily, weekly etc). To prevent people twiddling the calendar to do the events multiple times in a single real-world day, the game is coded to detect calendar changes and disable these events for 48 hours.

I've just cleared Alpha Sapphire, and have picked up X again to catch some stuff to trade over. My copy of Alpha Sapphire is physical, my copy of X is digital. I've been playing both on the same New 3DS. I still have my old original 3DS. Obviously I can't run X on the old 3DS without doing a full System Transfer over, so to trade between it and Alpha Sapphire, I'll need to put the Alpha Sapphire cart in my old 3DS.

**Will Alpha Sapphire detect the different system as a calendar change, and lock me out of time-sensitive events for 48 hours?** There's a few time-sensitive events I still need to do (and an ongoing effort to grind daily Secret Base flags), so if so I'll hang fire on trading stuff over for a while before I've done that.

---

*I know I could side-step this by pseudo-trading via Pokémon Bank, but that won't work for trade-evolving Pokémon. I also don't currently own a third Gen VI game to use as a 'man-in-the-middle' for trades*

Comment: I don't know how ORAS detects calendar/clock changes, but if that event is stored in the console itself as I suppose you should not encounter any problem playing on another console. **But** I can't prove that, I don't own another console. Anyway, if you don't find the answer you should look for a friend that owns a Gen VI game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Yes, it will detect the different system as a calendar change.

Physical 3DS games and their saves are hardware-agnostic. It won't differentiate between different 3DS systems, so a clock that's even (milli)seconds different will count as a calendar change.